# Can't stop form submissions with anchor tags on Contact Form 7 Plugin

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, validation, contact-form-7

I'm trying to stop anchor tags from being submitted into a contact form on my page. I've tried to block this with javascript, taking a few tips from Stack Overflow:

```
(function() {

    'use strict';

    // get elements of the form

    // textarea input, where the '<a' strings are coming in
    var input = document.querySelector('.wpcf7-textarea');
    var submit    = document.querySelector('.wpcf7-submit');
    var form      = document.querySelector('.wpcf7-form');

    // The actual contact-form-7 button is hidden since it 
    // seems to fire regardless of having an event.preventDefault()
    // on it, so a new button is created to replace it.
    function createButton() {

      var button = document.createElement('button');
      button.setAttribute('type', 'button');
      button.classList.add('form-button');
      // hide the original button
      submit.style.display = 'none';
      button.innerHTML = 'Send';
      // add new button to the form
      form.appendChild(button);

      // give the new button a click event that triggers
      // function hasLink()
      button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        hasLink(event);
      });
    }

    // check the message input for '<a' string
    function hasLink(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var value = input.value;
        // test the textarea input for '<a' string
        var result    = /<a/.test(value);
        if (result == true) {
            alert('Do not add links to the message.');
        }
        else {
        // submit to form if doesn't contain string
        document.createElement('form').submit.call(form);
        }
    }

    // create the new button on page load
    createButton();

})();
```

This works when the user is typing into the form, but for some reason I am still getting spam with anchor tags.

**Could it be because spammers have a cached version of the page that doesn't have the new javascript? Or maybe they have javascript disabled? Or they are able to programmatically submit to this form somehow? Is my only solution here to validate in PHP server-side? I am admittedly intimidated to do this in PHP. Any information on this is helpful. Thank you.**

Comment: Doing anything security-related clientside is always **bad**. Client-side validation should only **help** the user input sane content into the fields while backend validation makes sure you only accept data you can handle.

Comment: Thanks. I'll see about doing this in PHP somehow

Comment: Submitting to a form, without using the form, can be done easily via command line and `CURL`.

Comment: know that even with validation from javascript, it is good practice to always revalidate server-side. Because there are so many way to send a request to your server without using your form

Comment: @rpivovar Keep in mind, explicitly checking for `<a>` is not the right solution here. Instead use spam prevention wordpress plugins and encode HTML properly so it will just be interpreted as text only and not as code. See [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) and [SO related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996122/how-to-prevent-xss-with-html-php) for this.

Comment: Interesting -- thanks . I guess the big takeaway here is to do this server-side with PHP

Comment: Yup, something like `curl --data "field=value" http://example.com/secure_page.php` could be used to bypass any client side check. Maybe look into one of the Google captcha/recaptcha packages